# Trying to compare two dataframes with many columns in R row by row and label the incorrect rows

Tags: r, compare

What I'm essentially attempting to do is compare one data set that is a finite number of rows and columns - where each row is verified to be correct, to another data set that will change over time and I need to determine which rows in the second data set do not match up to the first.   This could be compared to I have the answer key (dataframe 1) and a dataframe with millions of rows that I need to compare to the answer key to determine which rows match.

I've read many solutions and have not yet found a concise solution - any suggestions out there?

Adding example data sets to support -
Data Set 1

```r
library(tibble)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~bc, ~var1, ~var2, ~var3,
  "A", 324, 468, 462,
  "B", 223, 362, 328,
  "C", 187, 200, 229,
  "D", 286, 455, 423)
```

Data Set 2

```r
df2 <- tribble(
  ~bc, ~var1, ~var2, ~var3,
  "A", 324, 468, 462,
  "B", 223, 362, 328,
  "C", 187, 200, 229,
  "D", 286, 455, 423,
  "A", 324, 468, 462,
  "B", 223, 362, 421,
  "D", 286, 455, 423)
```

What I am trying to do is check data set 2 by variable bc which matches data set 1.   For example the second D bc from data set 2 does not match does not match data set 1

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You should provide data examples as text, see we can copy/edit

Comment: Can you try using `dplyr::anti_join(df2, df1)` where `df2` is bigger dataset.

Comment: how does the second D bc from df2 does not match the df1? what are the criteria for matching? or do you mean the second B??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any data it is kind of hard to answer you.

Using the which function can tell you which rows match some criteria.
Below is an example how to use which.
You can change it to say which(df2$answers %in% df1$answer_key) or something similar

```
# Load the data
data(iris)

# Take a look
head(iris)
which_example <- c(5.4, 4.6)

# The way I think of which is to ask R "which rows in iris$Sepal.Length are 5.4?"
which(iris$Sepal.Length %in% 5.4)
which(iris$Sepal.Length %in% which_example)

# Once you have the rows, you can display only those specific rows and all or some columns
# The format is df[row,column] 
# Which gives the rows. You can leave column blank to get all or enter specific ones
iris[which(iris$Sepal.Length %in% 5.4),]
iris[which(iris$Sepal.Length %in% 5.4),c(2,4)]
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers above.    On more variant to the problem above.   I would need the variables in certain columns to be a text string.    Is there a way to make this logic work for text?   I couldn't make it work.   Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `setdiff` function from the `dplyr` package. It shows the rows that are different.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create example data frame
mtcars_edit <- mtcars
# Change the 1, 3, and 5 of wt column to 1
mtcars_edit$wt[c(1, 3, 5)] <- 1

# Apply the setdiff function
setdiff(mtcars, mtcars_edit)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Comment: Thank you for this.   I added a sample data above.    The first data set is limited in the number of rows, similar to an answer key.   The second data set has more rows and some repeat.   Some match, some don't .   I am working to identify the rows that do not match the answer key basically

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Ronak Shah in the comments, `anti-join` could be the solution here, if we understand you correctly. Here with simpler data sets for easier reproduction. For easier spotting of non-matches, they are negative numbers in the example data.

Also, in order to identify which columns are not matching, you can add an `id` variable.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~bc, ~var1, ~var2, ~var3, 
  "A",     1,     2,     3,
  "B",     4,     5,     6,
)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~bc, ~var1, ~var2, ~var3, 
  "A",     1,     2,     3,
  "B",     4,     5,     6,
  "A",     1,     2,     3,
  "B",     4,     5,    -1,
  "A",    -1,     2,     3,
  "B",     4,     5,     6,
)

# add id to identify which rows are not matching
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(id = row_number())


(df_unmatch <- dplyr::anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("var1", "var2", "var3")))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   bc     var1  var2  var3    id
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 B         4     5    -1     4
#> 2 A        -1     2     3     5

# list of non-match are the ids of df_unmatch
df_unmatch$id 
#> [1] 4 5

# with that you can create a new variable in df two, for instance
df2 %>% mutate(correct_match = if_else( !(id %in% df_unmatch$id), TRUE, FALSE))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   bc     var1  var2  var3    id correct_match
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <lgl>        
#> 1 A         1     2     3     1 TRUE         
#> 2 B         4     5     6     2 TRUE         
#> 3 A         1     2     3     3 TRUE         
#> 4 B         4     5    -1     4 FALSE        
#> 5 A        -1     2     3     5 FALSE        
#> 6 B         4     5     6     6 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: this worked great!   Thank you all so much for the help and thanks for the suggestions on how I can improve how I present questions

Comment: Great. I am glad it worked :) 
consider marking the question as solved (by clicking at the check sign on the left of the answer)